# Jenkins Pipeline: AWS EKS - EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request status code: 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-eks

I can successfully execute and create required Kuberneties cluster using the following command:

```
eksctl create cluster \
--name prod \
--version 1.17 \
--region us-west-2 \
--nodegroup-name linux-nodes \
--node-type t2.micro \
--nodes 2 \
--nodes-min 1 \
--nodes-max 2 \
--ssh-access \
--ssh-public-key jenkins-key-pair.pub \
--managed
```

But when I put it in the jenkinsfile, I get the following error:

'''Pipelines
Executors
Administration
Logout
ml-microservice-capstone-cloud-devops

```
Restart Create Kuberneties Custer
./run_kubernetes.sh
— Shell Script
6m 30s
+ ./run_kubernetes.sh

jenkins

[ℹ]  eksctl version 0.25.0

[ℹ]  using region us-west-2

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 30.75218ms

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 88.627854ms

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 172.57716ms

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 341.582944ms

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 574.895456ms

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 1.328733664s

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 1.988554304s

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 5.121512064s

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 14.262338304s

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 27.310317568s

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 51.545965568s

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 1m41.44976896s

[!]  retryable error (EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>

) from ec2metadata/GetMetadata - will retry after delay of 3m3.514882048s

Error: checking AWS STS access – cannot get role ARN for current session: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain

caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.

SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, .

EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found

caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

    status code: 404, request id: 

caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

  <title>404 - Not Found</title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>

 </body>

</html>



script returned exit code 1

1.23.2 
· Core 2.235.2 
· 6a14f41 
· 16th May 2020 02:37 AM
```

I am running it on ubuntu, where Jenkins and other tools are already configured.
I have tried above command, from cli, working fine for ubuntu and sudo root user. Don't know whats' wrong here.